# EF: How to use DB across multiple projects in the same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have three projects:

1. one containing all the models
2. one containing the controllers for my frontend
3. one containing the controllers for my customers frontend

I created a database for project (1) using entity framework (enable-migrations, add-migration, update-database).
Then I startet project (2), to create a new item and save this item in the previously created database.
However, instead of using said database, it instead created a new one (identical to the one from (1)) and saved the item there.
When starting project (3) I'm fairly sure the same thing would happen, creating a third identical database. However since (3) can't create new items, only read them, nothing happens instead. 
Now that's obviously not what I want, since I need to use the items created from (2) in (3) (and ideally have them saved in the database created in (1)), so how can I achieve, that every project uses the same database?

The connectionStrings across all three projects are identical:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-db.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The second project has a class 'Startup.Auth.cs', which the other ones don't. Since I'm not sure if it has something to with it, here's part of it:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyContext2.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

And here's the part of project (1) where I'm creating the context. The other projects don't have this:

```
public class MyContext2 : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyContext2()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Items> items { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }
    }
```

Intellisense works fine, it automatically fills out db.items as it's suppost to, so the references are set. I'm callng the database via `private MyContext2 db = new Context()`.

I can't get it working no matter what I try, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your connection strings are incorrect, because each project has own DataDirectory

Comment: Can you give me a starting point how the string should look, if I created it somewhere outside the projects, e.g. in the solution directory?

Comment: Can you use the SQL Server ?

Comment: A colleague was able to help me out. It's working now as it's supposed to. Thanks for sending me in the right direction. :D